# Hash # anchors in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

How can I mix hash anchors with Aurelia's routing?  For example, how would navigating to

```
<a href="#myContentDiv">Content</a>
```

work from a navbar constructed using Aurelia's router?

Comment: I believe you'd have to use push-state navigation. http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/2

Comment: I think I'm doing this wrong.  Reproducing a landing page is worthwhile from the PoV of maintenence and consistency but it should be its own (literal) SPA with hardcoded navbar.

The rest of the site can be as many SPAs as it needs to.

Comment: I was just looking at this earlier but couldn't find a solution :/

Comment: You should use the route-href custom element: https://elanderson.net/2017/01/aurelia-router-links-click-delegate-routing-parameters/